# Meteor Server Latency

Tags: meteor

I feel like I'm doing something wrong because my results seem to go against the very nature of Meteor's pitch of simulating client/sever interactions for speed. When I do any sort of database update using `Meteor.call()` the app has to wait for the round trip to the server, often resulting in a slow response or the user hitting the button twice. I just want to make sure I'm doing this correctly. Here's what I'm doing:

**Client:**

```
Template.shot.events({
'change #shot-status-select': function (event, template) {
    var new_status = $(event.target).val();

    var shot_id = Session.get('current_shot_id');
    Meteor.call('setShotStatus', shot_id, new_status, function (error, result) {
        if (result) {
            feedbackSuccess('Status changed to <b>'+new_status+'</b>');
        } else {
            feedbackError('Status change failed');
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
},
});
```

**And Server:**

```
...
'setShotStatus': function(shot_id, status) {
    var result = Shots.update({'_id': shot_id}, {$set: {'status': status}});
    if (result) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on here that are preventing your method from being latency compensated (it's making the complete round trip to the server).

First, if you execute a [Meteor.call](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call) on the client with a callback, it will always wait for the result from the server. Unfortunately, you can't just write it synchronously because a `call` will always return `undefined` on the client, and you need the returned result.

If you really want the result of the stub, you'd need to rewrite it like this:

```js
var args = [shot_id, new_status];
var result = Meteor.apply('setShotStatus', args, {returnStubValue: true});
if (result)
  feedbackSuccess('Status changed to <b>'+new_status+'</b>');
```

Note you should wrap the `call` in a `try`/`catch` if errors are likely. Also note that the client and server return values will not always match in the general case, so use this technique with that in mind.

Next, your method definition needs to be in a shared location for both the client and the server code (putting it somewhere under `lib` or in a package are good choices). If the client doesn't have the method code, it can't simulate it.

Recommended reading:

- [How to return value on Meteor.call() in client?](https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-return-value-on-meteor-call-in-client/1277)
- [Introduction to Latency Compensation](https://meteorhacks.com/introduction-to-latency-compensation)
- The "Latency Compensation" articles at the [Discover Meteor Encyclopedia](https://www.discovermeteor.com/encyclopedia)

Comment: `Meteor.call` usually returns `undefined`. I assume if the method is defined on both client and server, `Meteor.call` returns a proper value?

Comment: Yes, a definition on the client (stub) is a necessary in order for a value to be returned. See the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call) for a more complete description.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, David. Your answer got me on the right track, but I think there are a couple of nuggets in there that seemed too much to discuss in a comment. The main thing I found was this:

*The challenge of getting back to the "Meteor zero-latency" promise was as simple as moving all of my "server" methods to the `lib` directory.*

Literally, no code changes. After making the methods accessible to both client and server, Meteor did all of the heavy lifting of executing first on the client, then checking the result with the server result.

David's answer said that using a callback will always wait for a result from *the server*. I found that to be partly true, in that it will asynchronously wait for a result. Though depending on the accessibility of your methods, it could be a result from the client that you experience, not a round-trip from the server. Not using the callback will always return `undefined`, thus `result` will not work in the given example

Lastly, I moved truly private logic to the server only directory for security reasons.

Here's the code result:

**client/shot.js**

```
Template.shot.events({
'change #shot-status-select': function (event, template) {
    var new_status = $(event.target).val();

    var shot_id = Session.get('current_shot_id');
    Meteor.call('setShotStatus', shot_id, new_status, function (error, result) {
        if (!(result)) {
            feedbackError('Status change failed');
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
},
});
```

**lib/methods.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    'setShotStatus': function(shot_id, status) {
        var result = Shots.update({'_id': shot_id}, {$set: {'status': status}});
        if (result) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: You are correct - my initial answer was wrong in how a value could be read from the result of a stub call. I've corrected it with an example using `apply`, which should work in the simple case you presented.

Comment: Thank you for your help, David.